# JQuery Ajax call failing but service is hit

Tags: php, jquery, wcf, cross-domain

I'm not sure how to best explain this so bear with me.

I have the following in some javascript (using jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit(function(){

       var request = $.ajax({
          url: "myPage.php", //sits on localhost
          crossDomain: true,
          type: "POST",
          data: {
             var1 : "foo",
             var2 : "bar"
          }
        });

     request.done(function(res){
           alert("DONE");
     });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR , textStatus){
           alert(textStatus);
    });      
}
```

MyPage.php uses SoapClient to call a service.  And then return  some data.

I can directly call MyPage.php from the webBrowser and get a result (failed because there is no POST data).

If I try to make the MyPage.php call from the AJAX and put a breakpoint in my service, I see the service being called and returning a value.

But the request.Fail ALWAYS calls.  It appears that it just directly jumps to that fail before the service can even finish.

How would I remedy this?

Comment: `$.ajax` has built in properties named `success:` and `error:` that you can use for these purposes.  I'm not sure if this is the issue, but it's something to try.

Comment: I actually had the ':' in my code.  It's on a different machine with no internet access so I have to manually enter this stuff

Comment: do you have the colon between the data : { } like so?

Comment: if it is on a machine with no internet access then are you sure you should be using cross domain true?

Comment: The apache server sits on localhost.  The test service (WCF) sits on localhost:XXXX so I need cross-domain, right?

Comment: yes you need crossdomain can you show the response that you get from mypage.php does it have a call back function?

Comment: Sure.

if(conditionMet){
  echo "TRUE";
}

I've also tried going
$return["status"] = "true";
echo json_encode($return);

Both work if called directly or via a non ajax aproach.  I've also set the response type accordingly to jsonp when using the json return

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong but aren't you missing the colon between data and the data map? and then you should be doing `key : value` not `key = value` inside the map.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is wrong, it should be:

```
data: {
         var1: "foo",
         var2: "bar"
      }
```

Comment: I actually did have the ':' as I just commented - still no dice

Comment: @PSU_Kardi Your syntax in the edited question is still wrong. Can't you just copy and paste the real code?

Comment: @jeroen as he said in his comment its on a machine without internet access.

Comment: For the sake of argument let's assume the syntax is right as the arguments being passed to the service are being shown properly when I hit the break points.

Comment: @Jon Taylor It is actually possible to transfer files from one machine to another without using the internet ;-) But seriously, how are we expected to help if we can only see what the OP thinks his code looks like?

Comment: @jeroen lol yeah I know, but it may not be on a network and he may not have any means of transferring haha, unlikely I know. :)

Comment: OK, minus one typo the rest of the code is accurate.  I can not transfer from machine to machine.

Comment: @PSU_Kardi well then if you have corrected all your typos then your syntax is still wrong, you are still missing the colon between the key data and its value, the map of post data.

Comment: Once again, I'm not thinking it's syntax.  I have a breakpoint on my service and the values from these arguments are showing up.

Comment: @PSU_Kardi Have you checked the error log of the test service?

Comment: The test service is not throwing an error log.

If I were to directly go to http://localhost/myPage.php it hits the webservice and then echos the data I'd expect.

Comment: @PSU_Kardi You could try doing a normal (non-ajax...) POST to the service and see what comes up.

Comment: I tried that by making my form action="myPage.php" and it does what I'd expect it to do.  It passes & I get the expected data.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why, but apparently changing it from
$("#myForm").submit(function(){

And moving it into function SubmitForm(){...}

and then making the call from

Fixed the whole thing.  Thanks for the advice....